# ddrescue imaged my partition with no errors, but I can't mount the image as a loop device

Tags: mount, ntfs

I have a suspect ntfs drive with 2 partitions (from a win2k machine that has stopped fully booting except into safe mode).  I copied the 2 partitions separately using ddrescue.

The first was successful:

- this partition is labelled "system"
- `sudo ddrescue /dev/sdd1 /media/chris/WINDOWS/win2k_machine/sdd1/sdd1.img ~/sdd1_rescue.log` ran with no errors, no reported bad sectors.
- `sudo mount -o loop /media/chris/WINDOWS/win2k_machine/sdd1/sdd1.img /media/win2ksys/` (having used `mkdir` to create the mount point first.  So my approach seems fine.

The second won't mount:

- this partition is labelled "data"
  `sudo ddrescue /dev/sdd2 /media/chris/WINDOWS/win2k_machine/sdd2/sdd2.img ~/sdd2_rescue.log`  ran with no errors, no reported bad sectors. Note that I generated the command by editing the previous one.  The output file is the same size as the partition (as checked using gparted)
- `sudo mount -o loop /media/chris/WINDOWS/win2k_machine/sdd1/sdd2.img /media/win2kdata/` (again having used `mkdir` to create the mount point first, and again producing the command by editing the one from history) failed.

This fails with `mount: /media/win2kdata: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop8, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`  I'm not sure if there's a real fault in the image, or something is going wrong when I try to mount it.  `ntfsfix` reports

```
mounting volume... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 0: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x0)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 0: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x0)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error
Checking for self-located MFT segment... ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 0: Invalid argument
OK
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

Is this really a sign of imaging a corrupt drive, or is it an issue with how I'm trying to mount it?  I doubt I can run windows chkdsk on the image, and don't want to try running it on the real drive until I can be sure I've got a functioning image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have used the same log/state file for two different invocations of `ddrescue`. This file is used to keep track of the blocks and sectors that have been successfully (or unsucessfully) copied.

The first instance of `ddrescue` for `/dev/sdd1` created and updated the log/state file `~/sdd1_rescue.log`. The second instance of `ddrescue`, this time for `/dev/sdd2`, unintentionally used the same log/state file. This file had recorded that many of the blocks/sectors had been successfully copied so `ddrescue` was able to skip those. Unfortunately this meant that data capture from the second block device was largely ignored and the resulting image file was incomplete.